# Javascript: Removing part of a string ( get date string )

Tags: javascript, regex

I simply need to remove the time from this string `Sun Apr 26 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`

**Current solution which works**

```js
const dateTime = 'Sun Apr 26 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)';
const dateTimeArray = dateTime.split(' ');
const date = dateTimeArray.splice(0, 4);
console.log(date.join(' ')); // Correctly returns 'Sun Apr 26 2020'
```

Although this works I'm wondering if theres a more elegant? Or perhaps a regex?

Comment: Maybe a one-line like `dateTime.split(' ').splice(0, 4).join(' ')`

Comment: Use `dateTime = dateTime.replace(/ (\d{2}:){2}\d{2}.*/, '')`

Comment: create a date obj, and use myDate.toDateString() - let the language do the work

Comment: @sam : considering you seek to trim the string at fixed position, simple [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) may do the job: `'Sun Apr 26 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)'.slice(0,15)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`toDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

```js
const dateTime = 'Sun Apr 26 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)';

console.log(new Date(dateTime).toDateString())
```

Comment: This is the most sensible solution. Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
const dateTime = 'Sun Apr 26 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)';
const date = dateTime.substring(0, 15);
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
const dateTime = 'Sun Apr 26 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)';
console.log(dateTime.substring(0, 15));
```